# Is that possible to sync users from Windows Active Directory using SCIM 2.0 protocol?

Tags: c#, active-directory, scim2

I am trying to sync users from Windows Active Directory and ADFS Server using SCIM 2.0.

I google it to sync users from Windows AD and ADFS using SCIM 2.0 protocol.
Most of the results came for Azure Active Directory, OKTA and looks like cloud IdP providers.

Is that possible to sync users from Windows Active Directory and ADFS using SCIM 2.0 protocol?

Comment: Try it and see.   If you run into any issues come back and post it as a _new question._

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your edit does not make your question any more _too broad_ in addition to that you could _try it and see._ [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server Active Directory does not have a SCIM 2.0 client. You may be able to find third party methods to do this (i.e.: libraries to use in your own development, applications for usage/purchase that can do this), but it is not a native feature of Windows and will not be.

Syncing from AD -> AAD via Azure AD Connect, and then using Azure AD's SCIM provisioning features may be the best way to approach this.